# Best way to use dispatchqueue on condition in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to execute code with dispatchqueue. But only if a certain condition is true. I'm doing this so far, but there has to be a less ugly way.

```
if !sync {
    return self.tasksInQueue[userID]
}
return SYNC_QUEUE.sync {
    return self.tasksInQueue[userID]
}
```

Comment: Do you want this in one line ?

Comment: @adhelix : Sorry but whats ugly about this? You might be able to write it in slightly different way but all of them will have a if condition as your requirement clearly states that it needs one

Comment: The problem I have with it is the duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure its any cleaner.. but you could define a variable to define the common job to do...

```
let task = { self.tasksInQueue[userID] }
if sync { 
   return SYNC_QUEUE.sync { task() }
} else { 
   return task()
}
```

If this type of if happens in a bunch of places, you could in theory create some generic function to do the check for you..

```
func optionalSync <T> (_ sync: Bool, task: () -> T) {
    if sync { 
       return SYNC_QUEUE.sync { task() }
    } else { 
       return task()
    }
}
```

Then whenever you need to do an op...

```
optionalSync(sync) { self.tasksInQueue[userID] }
```